# How to change Visual Studio 2022 IDE icons?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, customization, visual-studio-2022, ide-customization

Is there a way to change icons that are used withing the Visual Studio 2022 IDE?

I tried looking for DLL files or image files containing the icons I want to change, but with no luck. On the Internet I did find resources with icons for various Visual Studio versions, but no information on how to change the icons of a Visual Studio IDE installation.

For example, I want to change icons of the Solution Explorer tool window which currently look like this:[image]
particularly the sync arrow, I'd like to revert it back to how it was in VS 2017:[image]

Can someone please tell me where these resources are being loaded from so I can try to replace them?

Comment: I wish I could resize them!

Comment: I'd like an answer to this please, if it's possible because I really dislike the source control icons and find them too indistinct. I'd much prefer coloured blobs (eg green for unchanged, amber for modified and red for conflicted)

Comment: @BobGear haven't found a solution, but with the newer VS updates, at least they changed that horrible Sync with Active Document icon back to how it was before